# Run a function after functions finished using python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

suppose I have 5 functions: f1() f2() f3() f4() f5().
I need to run f1 and f2 in parallel. After both finished I need to run f3 and f4 in parallel, then f5 after f3 and f4 finished. Using python.
Any help?

Comment: Are function f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 are dependent on each other? Is any interchange of data happening between them?

Comment: look into asyncio

Comment: Yes both f3,f4 need data from f1,f2 respectively. and f5 need data from f3 and f4.

Comment: There are many solutions to this: threading and `join()`, twisted, asyncio, gevent groups...

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) library.

Here is an example of what I came up with in python3:

```
import threading

def f1():
    print('f1')
def f2():
    print('f2')
def f3():
    print('f3')
def f4():
    print('f4')
def f5():
    print('f5')

t1 = threading.Thread(target=f1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=f2)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=f3)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=f4)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
f5()
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**multithreading**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to achieve what you want. First you need to start two threads to do functions one and two then you can use [`thread.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) to wait for the threads to terminate and then start the other functions. Here is an example of how it could be done:

```
import threading
l = [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5]
while l:
    if len(l) == 1:
        l.pop()()
    else:
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=l.pop())
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=l.pop())
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()
```